# OptaPlanner: how to compute the score on the given entities without constructing any solution

Tags: drools, optaplanner

On my project I have to find a way to initialize some entities and return their score without changing their values. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at docs section "Explaining the score" in the chapter "score calculation".

Basically, call `Solver.getScoreDirectoFactory()` and call `ScoreDirector.setWorkingSolution()` and `ScoreDirector.calculateScore()`.

Comment: Similar to how it's done here https://github.com/kiegroup/optaplanner/blob/7.24.0.Final/optaplanner-core/src/test/java/org/optaplanner/core/impl/score/director/easy/EasyScoreDirectorFactoryTest.java#L40-L45.